# MS Azure Closes Applications down when Disconnecting RDP

Tags: azure, metatrader4

I reckon my applications close down whenever my Azure VPS is disconnected (click the "X" at the top of the screen - NOT logging off). I have my MetaTrader programme running and not every trade is being executed whenever my pre-determined conditions are met.

I've looked at my logs for MetaTrader and there are no trade errors, no explanation as to why my trades are not executing. I've also looked at journals and there are no errors there either.

I've looked up my Windows Event Logs & I can't find anything for the MT4 application either.

The absence of error messages in my logs would say that my MT4 application is shutting down whenever I disconnect (resulting in no trades being executed - which is what you'd expect from an MT4 application that isn't running in the first place).

On the logs, it states that all symbols & EA's are being initialised - surely this shouldn't be saying this if they're running already.

Its bizarre and cannot get to the bottom of this. Can anyone shed some light on this and am I "barking up the wrong tree" as they say? Thanks in advance.

**In a nutshell:** Not all of my trades are being executed, & the presence of "initilsation logs" would indicate that MT4 is shutting down upon disconnection when its supposed to be running continuously.

Comment: This answer by Ryan Ries may help you. https://serverfault.com/questions/580916/stop-log-off-when-disconnected-from-rdp-session

Comment: I’ll try this, thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

You could try running the application as a service, this would allow the application to run in its own session and would not quit event after logging out:

> Microsoft Windows services, formerly known as NT services, enable you to create > long-running executable applications that run in their own Windows sessions. > These services can be automatically started when the computer boots, can be paused > and restarted, and do not show any user interface.

**Source:** https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/introduction-to-windows-service-applications

**Full steps on how to create a service:** 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/windows-services/how-to-create-windows-services

Comment: Thanks - I should add that the server is Windows 2012R2 and that I don’t log out, I just disconnect the RDP. :)

Comment: Ah I see, Could you check the RDP session timeout settings ? Not sure how your environment is setup, but it could possibly be the issue. 
this post has some instructions on how to check:https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/919ad175-8e9c-48ca-a814-37be9e5fb8c4/windows-server-2012-rds-server-session-time-limits-using-group-policy?forum=winserverTS

Comment: That's great but there's no "Remote Desktop Services" option under the server manager.......